# How to click on dynamic button using selenium Python?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am using Selenium Python and trying to access one of the dynamic created buttons which have same names and no ID.

By.XPATH and By.CLASS_NAME not working here. Any suggestions how can I click on this.[This is the button I want to click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0Cek.png)

This is how I am trying

```
btn=WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="BsGnbProv"]/div[1]/div[13]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/button[2]')))
```

This is xPath

```
//*[@id="BsGnbProv"]/div[1]/div[13]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/button[2]
```

This is Button element details

```
    <button class="w-100 btn btn-light btn-sm mr-1" data-bind="disable: 
          false, click: ViewNetworkFuncModal, visible: $root.IsReadOnly" 
        style="white-space: normal;">
        <span class="mr-1 fa fa-edit">
        </span>
        <span>View Configuration</span>
        </button>
```

This is the html of this div containing all buttons

```
<div data-bind="visible: GeneralProperties.NfCount() > 0, css: { 'bs-inactive': $root.IsInactive }" data-csv-category="Network Function Properties" class="card m-1 flex-shrink-0 ns-toggle"><div class="card-header"><label>Network Function Properties</label></div>
        <div class="overflow-auto card-body ns-width-md">
            <div class="form-group ns-width-md">
                <div class="col col-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                    <label class="d-block text-truncate property-label text-dark" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" style="text-decoration: underline;" title="" data-original-title="Function Type">Function Type</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                    <label class="d-block text-truncate property-label text-dark" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" style="text-decoration: underline;" title="" data-original-title="Managed Element ID">Managed Element ID</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- ko with: GeneralProperties.PuProperties -->
            <!-- ko foreach: NetworkFunctionDetailsList -->
            <div style="min-width: 480px;" class="form-group ">
        <div class="d-inline-flex align-items-center col col-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
            <label data-bind="text: NfTypeDesc, attr: { title: NfTypeDesc }" data-csv-label="Function Type" class="property-label d-block text-truncate text-dark" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="xPU">xPU</label>
        </div>
        <div class="d-inline-flex align-items-center col col-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
            <label data-bind="text: Id, attr: { title: Id }" data-csv-label="Managed Element ID" class="property-label d-block text-truncate text-dark" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="EAB8620065F0">EAB8620065F0</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
            <button class="w-100 btn btn-light btn-sm mr-1" data-bind="disable: $root.IsReadOnly, click: LoadNetworkFuncModal, visible: !$root.IsReadOnly()" style="white-space: normal; display: none;" disabled="">
                <span class="mr-1 fa fa-edit"></span>
            <span>Edit Configuration</span></button>
            <button class="w-100 btn btn-light btn-sm mr-1" data-bind="disable: false, click: ViewNetworkFuncModal, visible: $root.IsReadOnly" style="white-space: normal;">
                <span class="mr-1 fa fa-edit"></span>
            <span>View Configuration</span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko with: GeneralProperties.CuCpProperties -->
            <!-- ko foreach: NetworkFunctionDetailsList -->
            <div style="min-width: 480px;" class="form-group ">
        <div class="d-inline-flex align-items-center col col-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
            <label data-bind="text: NfTypeDesc, attr: { title: NfTypeDesc }" data-csv-label="Function Type" class="property-label d-block text-truncate text-dark" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="CU-CP">CU-CP</label>
        </div>
        <div class="d-inline-flex align-items-center col col-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
            <label data-bind="text: Id, attr: { title: Id }" data-csv-label="Managed Element ID" class="property-label d-block text-truncate text-dark" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="CUCP-at2200-eab8620065f0-1">CUCP-at2200-eab8620065f0-1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
            <button class="w-100 btn btn-light btn-sm mr-1" data-bind="disable: $root.IsReadOnly, click: LoadNetworkFuncModal, visible: !$root.IsReadOnly()" style="white-space: normal; display: none;" disabled="">
                <span class="mr-1 fa fa-edit"></span>
            <span>Edit Configuration</span></button>
            <button class="w-100 btn btn-light btn-sm mr-1" data-bind="disable: false, click: ViewNetworkFuncModal, visible: $root.IsReadOnly" style="white-space: normal;">
                <span class="mr-1 fa fa-edit"></span>
            <span>View Configuration</span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko with: GeneralProperties.CuUpProperties -->
            <!-- ko foreach: NetworkFunctionDetailsList -->
            <div style="min-width: 480px;" class="form-group ">
        <div class="d-inline-flex align-items-center col col-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
            <label data-bind="text: NfTypeDesc, attr: { title: NfTypeDesc }" data-csv-label="Function Type" class="property-label d-block text-truncate text-dark" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="CU-UP">CU-UP</label>
        </div>
        <div class="d-inline-flex align-items-center col col-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
            <label data-bind="text: Id, attr: { title: Id }" data-csv-label="Managed Element ID" class="property-label d-block text-truncate text-dark" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="CUUP-at2200-eab8620065f0-1">CUUP-at2200-eab8620065f0-1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
            <button class="w-100 btn btn-light btn-sm mr-1" data-bind="disable: $root.IsReadOnly, click: LoadNetworkFuncModal, visible: !$root.IsReadOnly()" style="white-space: normal; display: none;" disabled="">
                <span class="mr-1 fa fa-edit"></span>
            <span>Edit Configuration</span></button>
            <button class="w-100 btn btn-light btn-sm mr-1" data-bind="disable: false, click: ViewNetworkFuncModal, visible: $root.IsReadOnly" style="white-space: normal;">
                <span class="mr-1 fa fa-edit"></span>
            <span>View Configuration</span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko with: GeneralProperties.DuProperties -->
            <!-- ko foreach: NetworkFunctionDetailsList -->
            <div style="min-width: 480px;" class="form-group ">
        <div class="d-inline-flex align-items-center col col-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
            <label data-bind="text: NfTypeDesc, attr: { title: NfTypeDesc }" data-csv-label="Function Type" class="property-label d-block text-truncate text-dark" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="DU">DU</label>
        </div>
        <div class="d-inline-flex align-items-center col col-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
            <label data-bind="text: Id, attr: { title: Id }" data-csv-label="Managed Element ID" class="property-label d-block text-truncate text-dark" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="DU-at2200-eab8620065f0-1">DU-at2200-eab8620065f0-1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
            <button class="w-100 btn btn-light btn-sm mr-1" data-bind="disable: $root.IsReadOnly, click: LoadNetworkFuncModal, visible: !$root.IsReadOnly()" style="white-space: normal; display: none;" disabled="">
                <span class="mr-1 fa fa-edit"></span>
            <span>Edit Configuration</span></button>
            <button class="w-100 btn btn-light btn-sm mr-1" data-bind="disable: false, click: ViewNetworkFuncModal, visible: $root.IsReadOnly" style="white-space: normal;">
                <span class="mr-1 fa fa-edit"></span>
            <span>View Configuration</span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko with: GeneralProperties.RuProperties -->
            <!-- ko foreach: NetworkFunctionDetailsList -->
            <div style="min-width: 480px;" class="form-group ">
        <div class="d-inline-flex align-items-center col col-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
            <label data-bind="text: NfTypeDesc, attr: { title: NfTypeDesc }" data-csv-label="Function Type" class="property-label d-block text-truncate text-dark" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="RU">RU</label>
        </div>
        <div class="d-inline-flex align-items-center col col-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
            <label data-bind="text: Id, attr: { title: Id }" data-csv-label="Managed Element ID" class="property-label d-block text-truncate text-dark" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="RU-at2200-eab8620065f0-1">RU-at2200-eab8620065f0-1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
            <button class="w-100 btn btn-light btn-sm mr-1" data-bind="disable: $root.IsReadOnly, click: LoadNetworkFuncModal, visible: !$root.IsReadOnly()" style="white-space: normal; display: none;" disabled="">
                <span class="mr-1 fa fa-edit"></span>
            <span>Edit Configuration</span></button>
            <button class="w-100 btn btn-light btn-sm mr-1" data-bind="disable: false, click: ViewNetworkFuncModal, visible: $root.IsReadOnly" style="white-space: normal;">
                <span class="mr-1 fa fa-edit"></span>
            <span>View Configuration</span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Generally if a copied xpath is not working it's either due page loading or iframes.

Comment: @Atif can you give more details. e.g. your complete code. As in your above code, you have not shown whether you have done btn.click(), also if you can share the html code of the screenshot you have shared, we can try help with the XPath

Comment: @ketanvj its internal company portal, I am using btn.click() for click but problem is its not detecting/locating the button.

Comment: @Atif so are you getting NoSuchElementException?

Comment: Can you share a link to the page you are working on? Or entire XML of it? The picture you  shared is not helping and the XML block you shared is not unique.

Comment: @Atif : Can you post the html of entire table. You might need to identify the row first based on text and then following `View Configuration` button. Can you also check parent node of the table inside an `iframe` or not.

Comment: @KunduK I have posted html of enitre div where all this buttons are, if you can please suggest something

Comment: @Prophet I have share whole block div where these buttons are, any suggestions help.

Comment: @ketanvj I get time out exception because using waituntill.EC clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Atif, thanks for the detail HTML. Can you try the following XPath:

```
//button/span[text()='View Configuration']
```

This will give you the five buttons and then you can take action accordingly. I tried this and it is working fine.

Comment: `btn=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button/span[text()='View Configuration']")` I am using this and its giving me   " Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button/span[text()='View Configuration']"}"

Comment: My bad, I was not switching iframes, once I did and used this code, I found all buttons. Thank you  all for your help